# Logic Help: comparing values and taking the smallest distance, while removing it from the list of "available to compare"

Tags: c++, logic, root-framework

Okay, I have been set with the task of comparing this list of Photons using one method (IU) and comparing it with another (TSP). I need to take the first IU photon and compare distances with **all** of the TSP photons, find the smallest distance, and "pair" them (i.e. set them both in arrays with the same index). Then, I need to take the next photon in the IU list, and compare it to all of the TSP photons, **minus** the one that was chosen already.
I know I need to use a Boolean array of sorts, with keeping a counter. I can't seem to logic it out entirely.

The code below is NOT standard C++ syntax, as it is written to interact with ROOT (CERN data analysis software). 
If you have any questions with the syntax to better understand the code, please ask. I'll happily answer.

I have the arrays and variables declared already. The types that you see are called EEmcParticleCandidate and that's a type that reads from a tree of information, and I have a whole set of classes and headers that tell that how to behave.

Thanks.

```
  Bool_t used[2];
    if (num[0]==2 && num[1]==2) {
     TIter photonIterIU(mPhotonArray[0]);
     while(IU_photon=(EEmcParticleCandidate_t*)photonIterIU.Next()){
       if (IU_photon->E > thresh2) {
         distMin=1000.0;
         index = 0;
          IU_PhotonArray[index] = IU_photon;
         TIter photonIterTSP(mPhotonArray[1]);
         while(TSP_photon=(EEmcParticleCandidate_t*)photonIterTSP.Next()) {
           if (TSP_photon->E > thresh2) {
             Float_t Xpos_IU = IU_photon->position.fX;
             Float_t Ypos_IU = IU_photon->position.fY;
             Float_t Xpos_TSP = TSP_photon->position.fX;
             Float_t Ypos_TSP = TSP_photon->position.fY;
             distance_1 = find distance //formula didnt fit here //
             if (distance_1 < distMin){
               distMin = distance_1;;
               for (Int_t i=0;i<2;i++){
                 used[i] = false;
               } //for
             used[index] = true;
             TSP_PhotonArray[index] = TSP_photon;
             index++;
             } //if
           } //if thresh
         } // while TSP
       } //if thresh
     } // while IU
```

Thats all I have at the moment... work in progress, I realize all of the braces aren't closed. This is just a simple logic question.

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you have two arrays, and do not care about getting a minimized total distance, you can just brute force your way through this by having in the IU_photon and TSP_photon a field named partner or something, and remove from a temporary copy of the vectors.

Comment: im rather new to C++ (or any object language for that matter) so I dont understand what you mean. The idea is that I want to put these two particles in arrays at the same index, then run the same comparison for the next IU photon, excluding the ALREADY paired TSP photon.

Comment: Do something like
vector<IU_Photon> iuList;
vector<TSP_photon> tspList;
vector<PhotonPair> pairs;

for(all in iuList)
{
  find best match in tspList();
  PhotonPair mPair; // set it properly
  pairs.push_back(mPair);
  iuList.Remove(0);
  tspList.Remove(match);

Answer (score 1):

This may take a few iterations.

As a particle physicist, you should understand the importance of breaking things down into their component parts. Let's start with iterating over all TSP photons. It looks as if the relevant code is here:

```
TIter photonIterTSP(mPhotonArray[1]);
while(TSP_photon=(EEmcParticleCandidate_t*)photonIterTSP.Next()) {
  ...
  if(a certain condition is met)
    TSP_PhotonArray[index] = TSP_photon;
}
```

So `TSP_photon` is a pointer, you will be copying it into the array `TSP_PhotonArray` (if the energy of the photon exceeds a fixed threshold), and you go to a lot of trouble keeping track of which pointers have already been so copied. There is a better way, but for now let's just consider the problem of finding the best match:

```
distMin=1000.0;

while(TSP_photon= ... ) {
  distance_1 = compute_distance_somehow();
  if (distance_1 < distMin) {
    distMin = distance_1;
    TSP_PhotonArray[index] = TSP_photon;  // <-- BAD
    index++;                              // <-- VERY BAD
  }
}
```

**This is wrong.** Suppose you find a TSP_photon with the smallest distance yet seen. You haven't yet checked all TSP photons, so this might not be the best, but you store the pointer anyway, *and increment the index*. Then if you find another match that's even better, you'll store that one too. Conceptually, it should be something like this:

```
distMin=1000.0;
best_photon_yet = NULL;
while(TSP_photon= ... ) {
  distance_1 = compute_distance_somehow();
  if (distance_1 < distMin) {
    distMin = distance_1;
    best_pointer_yet = TSP_photon;
  }
}
// We've now finished searching the whole list of TSP photons.
TSP_PhotonArray[index] = best_photon_yet;
index++;
```

Post a comment to this answer, telling me if this makes sense; if so, we can proceed, if not, I'll try to clarify.